# Error Android Development - Label error (undefined label) , is there another way to write label?

Tags: java, android, label, break, continue

I have an error with label (lbl1). It says undefined label. I want to jump from

```
if(pNum == cNum)
                        {
                            code ...
                          break lbl1;
```

to

```
  lbl1:
    startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
```

but I get error every time. I get the same error with continue. Is there another way to write label in Java(Android)?

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //some code..


  lbl1:
    startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

      //some code..
            for (int i=0; i<15; i++)
            {
                final int j = i;
                btns[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        code ...

                        if(pNum == cNum)
                        {
                            code ...
                          break lbl1;
                        }else
                        {
                            Some code ......
                        }
                });
            }
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use a break label not from within a loop but within two anonymous inner classes. I don't think you can cross scopes with a break label. Unfortunately I can't tell what you are trying to do from your code other than you are not following expected practice for dealing with a 'onClick' event.

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to use a Label in your code. its not a good practice. Use a while loop or do...while loop instead and on reaching the certain condition break. Also there is some logic issues too. Why you are setting the onClickListener in a loop?